# How to update textview which shows current time position from a song

Tags: android, runnable, seekbar

So I have a seekbar, which works, when I drag it, the songs start playing from that position, but what I want is when I'm dragging the seekbar, I want to see my textview which displays the current song position updating when I'm dragging it, so the user can pick a specifiek time to start at.

Right now when I drag the seekbar, the textview doesn't change and only shows the last position when I started dragging it.

**This is my code**

```
private Runnable mUpdateTime = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long songCurrentTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        long songTotalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

        tvSongCurrentTime.setText(""+utilities.msToTimer(songCurrentTime));
        tvSongTotalTime.setText(""+utilities.msToTimer(songTotalTime));

        int progress = (int)(utilities.getProgressPercentage(songCurrentTime, songTotalTime));
        seekBar.setProgress(progress);

        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};

public void updateProgressBar(){
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTime, 100);
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTime);
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTime);
        int songTotalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration() ;
        int currentPosition = utilities.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), songTotalTime);

        mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);
        updateProgressBar();
}
```

**Here you can see what I'm trying to achieve**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBIUD.jpg

The first gif is what I have now, and the second one is what I want to get,

**EDIT**;

I still haven't found out how to do this, does someone know how to do it?
I think I have to put code inside the onProgressChanged, I tried adding the songs current time and the total duration, but how can I update the textview when I scroll the seekbar, like in the gifs I added in the post.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBIUD.jpg

Comment: I'm sorry if its kinda vague what i want

Comment: One minor point, you shouldn't need to update the song's duration every 1/10 of a second.  You could assume `tvSongTotalTime` will be constant.

Comment: What happens when you replace `updateProgressBar();` in `onStopTrackingTouch()` with `tvSongCurrentTime.setText(""+utilities.msToTimer(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));`?

Comment: Tried it and doesn't do it

Comment: What i want to achieve is that the currenttime changes when the users scrolls the seekbar so i can pick a specifiek time from a song, now when i scroll it stops at last position

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zEpWI, i added a gif so you can see what mean to achieve

Comment: Use the `onProgressChanged()` method, you can easily convert the `progress` variable to the right time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `onProgressChanged` is when the seekbar position changes:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if(fromUser) {
        long songCurrentTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        long songTotalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

        tvSongCurrentTime.setText(""+utilities.msToTimer(songCurrentTime));
        tvSongTotalTime.setText(""+utilities.msToTimer(songTotalTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: ill upload a gif, so i can clarify what i mean